# How to submit values from form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a form that is being created dynamically

```
<form action="addtable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <?php
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `tracker_item` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                { ?>
                    <input type="text"  placeholder="<? echo $row['heading']?>" name="<? echo $row['heading']?>" />

                <?}?>
              <button type="submit" name="add" alt="Add" value="Add" class="btn blue">Add</button>
</form>
```

But i a not able to understand how to carry the value of input to the addtable.php page

Can anyone please tell how to submit these values from this form

Comment: You should write your php code inside `<?php .. ?>` tags

Comment: @Shrikant Mavlankar sorry was a tying error, updated my post

Comment: Why you are adding submit button inside `while` loop, there should be one submit button for one form

Comment: print_r($_POST); in your addtable.php and submit button should be outside while loop

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you find a tutorial on how to use php / forms and start from there. There are plenty of useful guides / tutorials and it'll get you going faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your addtable.php, you need to print_r $_POST and see what inputs you're getting.

```
// addtable.php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);  // If you're expecting a file input
```

Also, you should modify your HTML a little:

```
<form action="addtable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tracker_item` ";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <input type="text"  placeholder="<? echo $row['heading']?>" name="<? echo $row['heading']?>" />
        <? }  ?>
    <button type="submit" name="add" alt="Add" value="Add" class="btn blue">Add</button>      <!--Place submit button outside loop -->
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your addtable.php:

```
<?php 

$inputValue = $_POST['input_name'];

//the $inputValue is the input value that you posted from form.
echo $inputValue;


?>
```

Comment: its not displaying any value

Answer (score 0):

try this , 
addtable.php

```
   <?php
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
       echo "Field ".htmlspecialchars($key)." is ".htmlspecialchars($value)."<br>";
      }
    ?>
```

i hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons your PHP is not functioning correctly is because your PHP block, is not placed inside of PHP tags.

Your code **should** look like this:

```
<form action="addtable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?php // added the PHP tags
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `tracker_item` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?> // escaped the php tag 
            <input type="text"  placeholder="<?= $row['heading']; ?>" name="<?= $row['heading']; ?>" />
            <button type="submit" name="add" alt="Add" value="Add" class="btn blue">Add</button>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Notice how I also escaped PHP when I wanted to display any HTML. Of course, you could simply echo these out, but you can do this too! Personal preference, really.

Another little alteration I made was, rather than using `<?php echo ... ?>` you can simply use `<?= $row['...']; ?>`. It is faster and cleaner too!

Comment: button in while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of heading and access it in php:

```
<form action="addtable.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <?php
       $sql="SELECT * FROM `tracker_item` ";
       $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
       {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
          {
    ?>
            <input type="text"  placeholder="<?php echo $row['heading']; ?>" name="heading[]"> />
    <?
          }
    ?>
            <button type="submit" name="add" alt="Add" value="Add" class="btn blue">Add</button>
    <?php
       }
    ?>
</form>
```

In addtable.php:

```
$headingArray = $_POST['heading']; // here you will get all the heading in array format
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue in submit button, you looping submit button with same name, try to put submit button out of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

To receive data in addtable.php you have to get them by name property of inputs in the form. So you have to define the names of inputs or to retrieve them again from db in addtable.php

Comment: The OP appears to be a new programmer in the PHP field. So giving him sort of an example (code block) would be a good idea!

Comment: <?php
$value_1=isset($_POST['input_name_1'])?$_POST['input_name_1']:'';
$value_2=isset($_POST['input_name_2'])?$_POST['input_name_2']:'';
$value_3=isset($_POST['input_name_3'])?$_POST['input_name_3']:'';
ect